# How to store conversion of datetime in a new column with new columnname which it is possible to use ORDER BY on?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a datetime column and i want to delete duplicate "DATES" from this column.

Datatype of my existing column is datetimeoffset(7):

```
2018-06-17 00:44:13.0000000 +00:00
```

I'm now able to extract the dates like this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), mytimestamp_column, 102) FROM [dbo].[myTable] 
where mycondition = 1223445
```

This gives me a column like this:

```
(No column name)
2018.06.18
2018.06.17
2018.06.16
.... and so on
```

Now i'm trying to give this new column a name, so i can use "ORDER BY" on this column to sort the result. First question, how do i do this, i'm trying the following and get syntax error:

```
select newcolumn from(
(SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), mytimestamp_column, 102) FROM [dbo].[myTable] 
where mycondition = 1223445) as newcolumn
order by newcolumn desc
```

Second question: How do i delete the duplicate days from the result set in an easy manner, i'm trying to avoid long and complex expressions/formulas?

tnx :)

Comment: To remove duplicates use DISTINCT just after the outmost SELECT and before the column list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this using `Row_Number` as shown below.

```
DELETE A FROM(
    SELECT
      Row_Number() Over(Partition By mytimestamp_column Order By 
      mytimestamp_column) as RN, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), mytimestamp_column, 102) as 
      NewColumn
      FROM [dbo].[myTable] 
      --where mycondition = 1223445) as newcolumn
     )A where RN > 1
```

You can find the demo [Here](https://rextester.com/HXUYT25912).

Comment: I get invalid column name A for this one.

Comment: @otk Please check the demo.

Comment: So this is to only delete the data in one column 'A'? I need to delete all rows in my original table that has RN > 1.

Comment: @otk It will delete all column of original table you can check with creating another column also. Please check this demo https://rextester.com/WZNZJ75855

Comment: Hi, yeah I'm checking the demo. And that runs, but when i run it in my environment it reports Invalid column name 'A'.  What does A represent in this case (an actual column?) ?

Comment: And in addition, I'm for now Using SELECT instead of DELETE because i need to check what I'm deleting. But i dont see that it should cause any difference?

Comment: @otk Here A is the name of table. As you can see no column of name A is in the table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188603/discussion-between-suraj-kumar-and-otk).

Answer (score 4):

Just order by the quantity/column or alias directly:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), mytimestamp_column, 102) AS col
FROM [dbo].[myTable] 
WHERE mycondition = 1223445
ORDER BY
    col DESC;
```

You don't really need to subquery here.

Answer (score 3):

in your query newcolumn is a table (subquery) alias not column alias , you have to write your query below way

```
select * from
 (
(SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), mytimestamp_column, 102) as col -- column alias
FROM [dbo].[myTable] 
where mycondition = 1223445
) as newcolumn --subquery name 
order by col desc
```

Comment: Why is a subquery necessary here?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen there is no need subquery i just mentioned what he does regarding his error point as you already answered the query without subquery that's why i didn't added that part in my answer

Answer (score 1):

Use Common table expression to create table like schema and use it for further query.

```
 GO
 ;WITH CTE AS 
 (
  SELECT Row_Number() Over(Partition By mytimestamp_column Order By 
   mytimestamp_column) as Slno, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), mytimestamp_column, 102) as newcolumn  
  FROM [dbo].[myTable] where mycondition = 1223445)
  Select * from cte where Slno>1 order by newcolumn desc
  GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Just convert the value to a date to extract the date:

```
convert(date, mytimestamp_column)
```

As in:

```
order by convert(date, mytimestamp_column)
```

To remove duplicates from the *result set*, use window functions:

```
select newcolumn
from (select t.*,
             convert(date, mytimestamp_column) as mydate,
             row_number() over (partition by convert(date, mytimestamp_column) order by mytimestamp_column) as seqnum
      from t
      where mycondition = 1223445
     )
where seqnum = 1;
```

Only use `delete` if you want to delete rows *permanently* from tables.